# How to configure maxDegreeOfParallelism for cosmosdb in Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I want to configure the **CosmosQueryRequestOptions.maxDegreeOfParallelism** while using the CosmosRepository. I didn't find any documentation around it.

This blog shows how to configure and use this setting through a custom client, but I want to use the repository instead. https://medium.com/@middha.nishant173/improve-query-performance-with-azure-cosmosdb-java-sdk-v4-db1fc54cb484

Answer (score 2):

`CosmosQueryRequestOptions` is implementation detail for Spring Data Cosmos SDK, so customers cannot set it through spring application.
This can be implemented as a new feature, and can be exposed through `application.properties` via `query.maxDegreeOfParallelism` - which customers can opt in if they want.

Default value for `maxDegreeOfParallelism` is 0, which is the right value for single partition queries. For cross partition queries in the current SDK version, you can get the `cosmosClient` through spring boot `applicationContext` and run the query directly against the client. This example shows how to do it - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos-test/src/test/java/com/azure/spring/data/cosmos/repository/integration/PageableAddressRepositoryIT.java#L144

Comment: Answered inline, edited my original answer!